# Why does a List use almost 3x the memory of an array?

Tags: c#, list, memory

I'm trying to add a lot of data to a List, but it seems to use a lot more RAM than an array does. I was wondering why that is and if there's a better solution.

This solution with an array takes about 78 MB of RAM. Makes sense since 4 byte * 20000000 ~= 76 MB:

```
float[] arrayValues = new float[20000000];

for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
     arrayValues[i] = i;
```

But this solution with a list takes 206 MB (!!):

```
List<float> listValues = new();

for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
     listValues.Add(i);
```

How can that be? It's basically doing the same thing - saving 20000000 float values. Where is that additional 128 MB coming from? And is there a better way that doesn't produce so much overhead?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage of the list? Your list will need to resize many times as it grows dynamically - is it possible that you're including those old, too-small arrays which have since been discarded (but might not yet have been garbage collected) in your measurement? Have you tried giving the list an initial capacity, i.e. `new(20000000)`?

Comment: I'm looking at the RAM Usage in the Task Manager and the Profiler in Visual Studio. VS is a bit higher, the values I mentioned are from the Task Manager.

Comment: Hint `var listValues = new List<float>(20000000)`.

Comment: @Zelos You're probably looking at the old intermediate arrays that the `List` allocated then, which haven't yet been garbage collected (the runtime will only garbage collect when it needs to; things larger than 85k get allocated on the so-called Large Object Heap, which is expensive to collect and so is collected infrequently).

Comment: @Zelos `a List use almost 3x the memory of an array?` *it doesn't*. A `List` uses an array. Your code though causes a ton of reallocations of the internal array

Comment: @Zelos every time the internal buffer is full `List<T>` will allocate a new one with twice the size and copy the old data. The old buffer now needs to be GCd. This doesn't just use a lot of memory, it also causes memory fragmentation. After a while memory may be so fragmented that the memory allocator can't find a single continuous memory area to create the new buffer and throw and `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: As a ballpark, `List<T>` starts off with an array of size 4 and doubles it every time it runs out of space, so for 20000000 elements it's resizing its internal array somewhere around 23 times. So there are 22-ish old arrays sitting around, ranging in size from 4 bytes to 16.8M, which might not have been reclaimed yet. Giving the list an initial capacity avoids all of that, and it allocates an array of the correct size at the start.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You won't get an OutOfMemoryException here -- the GC will run before that happens (it's triggered by an out-of-memory condition), and will collect the old unused arrays

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude See for yourself: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646, or the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0#remarks -- "*It implements the `IList<T>` generic interface by using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.*" . It is a list, but it's not a linked list, if that's what you're getting confused with.

Comment: You're all correct, giving the List an initial value leads to pretty much the same memory allocation in the Task Manager, so it's those old arrays that the GC didn't get yet. But I noticed that in the VS Diagnostic Tools the array version shows as 101 MB and List as 191MB. Why is that? They are the same in Task Manager.

Comment: Try *collecting garbage*, `GC.Collect(2);` before measuring: `List<T>` has to reallocate memory in order to increase its size (and thus produces garbage - earlier allocated memory).

Comment: To see what's actually going on use BenchmarkDotNET with the `MemoryDiagnoser` attribute. This will show the actual memory used, allocations, GC generations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `Add` new items into a `List<T>` it has to do *memory reallocation* to have enough space for these new items.
Let's have a look at the process:

```
  List<float> listValues = new();

  int capacity = listValues.Capacity;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    listValues.Add(i);

    if (capacity != listValues.Capacity) {
      capacity = listValues.Capacity;

      Console.WriteLine(capacity);
    }
  }
```

**Outcome:**

```
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432 // <- Finally, list allocates memory for 33554432 items
```

As you can see, now `33554432` items are allocated and `4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 16777216` are *garbage*. In the *worst* case we have
`33554432` allocated items and `33554432` garbage items; in total `33554432 + 33554432 = 67108864 ~ 3 * 20000000` and you can see this **3 factor**.

What can you do?

Specify the `Capacity` in order to avoid realloaction (typical solution):

```
  // We can avoid all this mess with reallocations
  // by specifing required capacity: 20000000 items in our case 
  List<float> listValues = new(20000000);

  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    listValues.Add(i);
  }
```

Collect all garbage before measuring:

```
  // Business as usual
  List<float> listValues = new();

  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    listValues.Add(i);
  }

  // Collect garbage to measure real List efficency:
  // List allocates 33554432 items vs. 20000000 in case of array 
  // About ~70% overhead 
  GC.Collect(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I got it now. Calling GC.Collect() indeed reduces RAM usage to 78 MB. But I've noticed that calling it again afterwards, the RAM Usage does not go back down to what it was before. Before filling the List I'm at 8 MB, and afterwards I'm at 15 MB. It never goes back down, and 15 MB seems to be the new baseline. Why is that?

Comment: @Zelos: Extra 15 MB can be some *static data* (say, from assembly loaded). You start using `List<T>` - System.Collections.Generic and .net loaded assembly(es) with types, static fields, resources etc.

Comment: When allocating objects they can end up in different places in memory. It depends on how long they have been in memory and how big these objects are. And when creating many objects, the memory can become fragmented, (e.g. have holes in the total memory used where some available memory exists). Best practice is to do as few allocations as you can, so in your case it's better to pre-allocate a big List in case you'll need the space.

Comment: For more background, read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511& and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511& and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&#a-debugger

Comment: Remember that the .NET GC is a compacting garbage collector -- fragmentation is handled during a GC. Except for the LOH, with objects over 85k, of course.